# Next-auth How to redirect when 401?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth, rtk-query

I am working with Next-auth and rtk query. I need that when a request, any, returns a 401 unauthorized error, the page redirects directly to the login. How is it done?

I added 'maxAge: 60' to the [...nextauth].js file and also refetchInterval={30} refetchOnWindowFocus={true} to the  component tried to find a similar solution, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

since you're using rtk query, you can update your apiSlice baseQuery function, to check for auth errors and redirect on that, my suggestion is this:

create a base query where you check for the 401 and any other error you want:

```js
    // try to execute the req, if it fails logout, and redirect to login.
    const baseQueryWithAuth: BaseQueryFn = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
      const result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
      if (result.error?.status === 403 || result.error?.status === 401) {
        // non authorized, then redirect to login page.
        // if we have jwt, here u should update the access token
        localStorage.removeItem(TOKEN_KEY_IN_LOCAL_STORAGE);
        Router.replace('/auth/login');
      }
      return result;
    };
```

in the snippet above, when I'm referring to token deletion as logout because the token is already invalid in the DB, so I just need to delete it in the front, so no invalidate request is needed.

the mentioned `baseQuery` can be done like this:

```js
const baseUrl = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_PROTOCOL}://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_HOST}/api`;
const TOKEN_KEY_IN_LOCAL_STORAGE = 'SavedToken';
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl,
  // credentials: 'include',
  prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
    // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
    const token = localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY_IN_LOCAL_STORAGE);
    if (token) {
      headers.set('Authorization', token);
    } else {
      Router.replace('/auth/login');
    }
    return headers;
  },
});
```

and then now since you have a working base query with auth support, you can use that to create a main rtk query `apiSlice` for your project:

```js
// create api
export const apiSlice = createApi({
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithAuth,
  tagTypes: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'],
  endpoints: (_builder) => ({}),
});
```